# SQL: Help normalize data

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, database-normalization

I have a table with a column like this:

```
Name
-----
ABC\name1
DEFG\name2 
ABC\name3
xy\name4
ghi\name5
```

I am trying to separate the fields in the Name column on the "\" character. Either deleting everything before "\" including the "\"  or separating the Name column into 2 new columns like the following:

```
Domain  Name
------------
ABC     name1
DEFG    name2 
ABC     name3
xy     name4
ghi     name5
```

How do I / what would a query look like to update my table to look like this?

Thanks!

Comment: And what's the question?

Comment: Please read up on CHARINDEX and SUBSTRING. They are fully documented in Books Online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Sir Aaron Bertrand's comment, you ca use [**SUBSTRING**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx) and [**CHARINDEX**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx):

```
;WITH TestData(Name) AS(
    SELECT 'ABC\name1' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'DEFG\name2' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'ABC\name3' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'xy\name4' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'ghi\name5'
)
SELECT
    Domain = SUBSTRING(Name, 1, CHARINDEX('\', Name) - 1),
    Name = SUBSTRING(Name, CHARINDEX('\', Name) + 1, LEN(Name) - CHARINDEX('\', Name))
FROM TestData
```

**RESULT**

```
Domain     Name
---------- ----------
ABC        name1
DEFG       name2
ABC        name3
xy         name4
ghi        name5
```